# depends but it is not going to be installed - debian

Tags: firefox, debian, aptitude

I'm using debian lenny (stable). I'm trying to downgrade firefox (iceweasel) 3 to latest 2. I uninstalled iceweasel, created pin, added etch repo, updated apt... and i'm getting:

```
apt-get install iceweasel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
iceweasel is already the newest version.
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  iceweasel: Depends: libmyspell3c2 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxp6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do i fix this?

my /etc/apt/preferences:

```
Package: iceweasel
Pin: version 2.0.0.19-0etch1
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
#
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.2 _Lenny_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20090629-11:06]/ lenny main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.2 _Lenny_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20090629-11:06]/ lenny main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ lenny main

deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main

deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
apt-get -f install
```

with no packages specified?

Comment: i'm not sure if i should, i googled for "apt-get f install" and there were some usenet discussions pointing out that it might break the system (i'm not sure if that's true or not, though)

Comment: If you're being asked to do this in the first place, something has already broken. When you run it, examine each change it wants to ensure it makes sense.